# Better way to remap 16-Key Touch keypad

Tags: arduino-nano

I have written a code that remaps the buttons of `TTP229` touch keypad which works as it is. Is there any way to optimize this code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LCD.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

#define SCL_PIN 11
#define SDO_PIN 12
#define I2C_ADDR    0x3F
#define BACKLIGHT_PIN     3
#define En_pin  2
#define Rw_pin  1
#define Rs_pin  0
#define D4_pin  4
#define D5_pin  5
#define D6_pin  6
#define D7_pin  7

byte Key;
String keyRemap[12][2] = {
    {"1","1"},{"2","2"},
    {"3","3"},{"5","4"},
    {"6","5"},{"7","6"},
    {"9","7"},{"10","8"},
    {"11","9"},{"14","0"},
    {"13","Clear"},{"15","Enter"}
};

LiquidCrystal_I2C  lcd(I2C_ADDR,En_pin,Rw_pin,Rs_pin,D4_pin,D5_pin,D6_pin,D7_pin);

void setup()
{
    lcd.begin (16,2);
    lcd.setBacklightPin(BACKLIGHT_PIN,POSITIVE);
    lcd.setBacklight(HIGH);
    lcd.home ();

    pinMode(SCL_PIN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(SDO_PIN, INPUT);
}
void loop()
{
    Key = Read_Keypad();
    if (Key != 0) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor (0,0);
        for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
            if (Key == keyRemap[x][0].toInt()) {
                lcd.print(keyRemap[x][1]);
            }
        }
        delay(160);
    }
}
byte Read_Keypad(void)
{
    byte Count;
    byte Key_State = 0;

    for (Count = 1; Count <= 16; Count++)
    {
        digitalWrite(SCL_PIN, LOW);
        if (!digitalRead(SDO_PIN))
            Key_State = Count;
        digitalWrite(SCL_PIN, HIGH);
    }
    return Key_State;
}
```

Comment: What do mean exactly by "optimize the code"? Do you have problems with its speed, its size, or anything? What is your question really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to optimize this code:

Absolutely, yes. Don't use `String` for this, you are seriously wasting memory. Instead you can use a `struct`:

```
struct keymap {
    uint8_t code;
    const __FlashStringHelper *value;
};

const struct keymap keyRemap[] = {
    { 1, F("1") },
    { 2, F("2") },
    { 3, F("3") },
    { 5, F("4") },
    { 6, F("5") },
    { 7, F("6") },
    { 9, F("7") },
    { 10, F("8") },
    { 11, F("9") },
    { 14, F("0") },
    { 13, F("Clear") },
    { 15, F("Enter") },
    { 0, 0 }
};

void loop() {
    int Key = Read_Keypad();

    if (Key != 0) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

        for (int x = 0; keyRemap[x].code != 0; x++) {
            if (Key == keyRemap[x].code) {
                lcd.print(keyRemap[x].value);
            }
        }

        delay(160);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you stop posting faster than me :)

Comment: I can't help it if I had 2 coffees this morning :P

Comment: You could also fully populate the table with all possible answers and then this would remove the loop when looking for answers, but you would need to handle 4 and 12 specially.

Comment: It would remove the need for the struct entirely then - a simple 16-entry array. But where would the fun in that be?

Comment: @Majenko I used your code and I got an [error](http://pastebin.com/ddPVFKMQ)

Comment: @conquistador Probably something odd with the Arduino IDE (that I never use) - some flag not being set or being set that shouldn't really be being set.